# compare 2 dates in a slick query seems hard

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick

helllo

I can't adapt this example of code : https://github.com/pedrofurla/slick-demo/blob/master/src/main/scala/slickdemo/domain/Person.scala.

it deals with the capacity of comparing dates in a slick query. The difficulty is you can't access to the date field(to extract for example the year, the month and the day) because the query uses Column types.

I searched and found the example above, but I can't adapt it.

here is my code:

the Table:

```
class Personnes( tag : Tag ) extends Table[ Rdv ]( tag, "RDV" ) {

     def id = column[ Int ]( "ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc )
     def nom = column[ String ]( "NOM", O.NotNull )
     def prénom = column[ String ]( "PRENOM" )
     def sexe = column[ Int ]( "SEXE" )
     def télPortable = column[ String ]( "TELPOR" )
     def télBureau = column[ String ]( "TELBUR" )
     def télPrivé = column[ String ]( "TELPRI" )
     def siteRDV = column[ String ]( "SITE" )
     def typeRDV = column[ String ]( "TYPE" )
     def libelléRDV = column[ String ]( "LIBELLE" )
     def numRDV = column[ String ]( "NUMRDV" )
     def étape = column[ String ]( "ETAPE" )
     def dateRDV = column[ java.sql.Date ]( "DATE" )
     def heureRDVString = column[ String ]( "HEURE" )
     def statut = column[ String ]( "STATUT" )
     def orderId = column[ String ]( "ORDERID" )

     def * = ( id.?, nom, prénom, sexe, télPortable, télBureau, télPrivé,
        siteRDV, typeRDV, libelléRDV, numRDV, étape, dateRDV, heureRDVString,
        statut, orderId ) <> ( Rdv.tupled, Rdv.unapply _ )

  }
```

and the method:

```
def sqlite_findBetween( début : java.util.Date, fin : java.util.Date ) : List[ Rdv ]=  db_sqlite.withSession { implicit db : Session =>

   def débutTime:org.joda.time.DateTime = new DateTime(début)
   def finTime=new DateTime(fin)


     val query = for {
        p <- personnes
        if  (p.dateRDV > débutTime && finTime < p.dateRDV)
     } yield p
     query.list

  }
```

thanks!

ps : I forgot the error : near the date comparison, I get :

```
Cannot perform option-mapped operation with type: (java.sql.Date, org.joda.time.DateTime) => R for base type: (java.sql.Date, java.sql.Date) => Boolean
```

ps2 : here is the utility file : I have obviously added it in the classpath : https://github.com/pedrofurla/slick-demo/blob/master/src/main/scala/slickdemo/dal/JodaTimeSupport.scala, with this :

```
import models.JodaTimeSupport

package models {

    trait sqlite extends JodaTimeSupport {...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from creating your own implicit `MappedColumnType` from `java.sql.Date` to `org.joda.time.DateTime`, you can try the popular *slick-joda-mapper* found [here on Github](https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper).

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!