# Filter query based on sum of LocalDate and Option[Int] in Slick

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick, slick-3.0

I have a DB table with two columns:

```
startDate -> date type
duration -> nullable integer
```

In my Slick configuration these columns are defined as `LocalDate` (I'm using Joda) and `Option[Int]` respectively.

Now, I want to write a query which given a date `givenDate` it gives me back all the rows where `duration` is defined and `startDate + duration < givenDate`.

I was expecting something like that:

```
db.run(table.filter(t => {
  t.duration.isDefined && 
  t.startDate < givenDate.minusDays(t.duration.getOrElse(0))
}))
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work because the `t.duration.getOrElse(0)` is not really an integer, but a `Rep[Int]`.

How can I do that?

Technologies I'm using: Scala, Slick 3.1, Joda Time, slick-joda-mapper

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349547/compare-2-dates-in-a-slick-query-seems-hard look at this question, might help you

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk Unfortunately this doesn't help. I can compare dates (as I mentioned I'm using `slick-joda-mapper`). What I can't do is modify a date in the query and then compare it.

Comment: I don't know how slick-joda-mapper works, but have you tried wrap givenDate in Rep? Maybe then it will allow to perform operation on Rep[Int]?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found answer for your question. So basically you can't unwrap Rep, because of database type safety. Additionaly you don't have any chance to invoke scala function **inside** database engine, that is why we can't use `minusDays(t.duration.getOrElse(0))` in any way. Slick also don't have purpose to implement **every** operation on every datatype because of course of different database engines. But still if you want to invoke date operations on your database you must check if it supports date operations. My example is on H2 database, here we go:

**defined data**

```
case class DateTest(id: Option[Int] = None, date: LocalDate, duration: Int) extends BaseEntity

  class DateTestTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[DateTest](tag, None, "DateTest") {

    override val id: Rep[Option[Int]] = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def date: Rep[LocalDate] = column[LocalDate]("date")

    def duration = column[Int]("duration")

    def * = (id, date, duration) <>(DateTest.tupled, DateTest.unapply)

  }

  val dateTests: TableQuery[DateTestTable] = TableQuery[DateTestTable]
```

**inserted data**

```
H2Connector.dateTests ++= Seq(
  DateTest(Some(1), new LocalDate(2017,3,4),15),
  DateTest(Some(2), new LocalDate(2017,2,17),15)
)
```

**repository**

```
  val addDays: (Rep[String], Rep[Int], Rep[LocalDate]) => Rep[LocalDate] = SimpleFunction.ternary[String,Int,LocalDate,LocalDate]("DATEADD")

  def dateWithDuration(givenDate: LocalDate): Future[Seq[DateTest]] ={
    filter(auth => auth.date < addDays("DAY",auth.duration*(-1),givenDate))
  }
```

So in last piece of code you can see how this is implemented. First of all H2 supports this operation on date [DATEADD](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd), and Slick allows you to implement custom function, which will use database function. In this way, you can use REP wrapped values, and it will allow slick to stay with its type safe implementation.

With those tests:

```
  "TestDate " should {
    "return date with small duration " in {
      println(waitForResult(testDate.dateWithDuration(new LocalDate(2017,3,15))))
    }
    "return every date " in {
      println(waitForResult(testDate.getAll))
    }
  }
```

results are:

```
Vector(DateTest(Some(2),2017-02-17,15))
Vector(DateTest(Some(1),2017-03-04,15), DateTest(Some(2),2017-02-17,15))
```